# gradle error linked to namespace on build.gradle file

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I keep have this error, but I already did what they ask me to do.

This is the error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':audio_service'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

     android {
         namespace 'com.example.namespace'
     }

     If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant; please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

BUILD FAILED in 2m 56s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is my build.gradle file as asked by khoi.

thank everyone

Comment: I think that you should put your build.gradle coding file, so that it is easy to understand.

Comment: Hi, this is the link for my build.gradle  link : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kvjNMsf5Zw62xzvkEQWb7jKmbvPUsGj7YcIcKY_Tsj4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you share your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: This is my androidmanifest.xml : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K0tCVFvXzy5b9kniB4MMPgxLfAX8qNobU7FnC93qvFw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you tell me how you change or add a namespace...  Visual Studio Code or Android Studio? It's not recommended to change the namespace directly from VSCode. Instead, you should open Android Studio, make the necessary changes there, and then sync the project.

Comment: I use android studio and i add it in the build.gradle file

Comment: If remove the audio_service library from current project and compile it, still get the same error?

Comment: Yes, i still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution for my problem.

1. tools tab > flutter > open Android module in Android Studio
2. file tab > Project structure > project
3. Android Gradle Plugin version to : 7.0.4 and Gradle Version to 7.6.1
4. flutter pub upgrade
5. update all your plugins

Comment: what did u mean in 3 ?

Comment: you have to put this value

Comment: still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version of audio_service in pubspec.yaml file. The issue should have been resolved